# How to render some text with given font file?

Tags: fonts, imagemagick

How to just render some text with the given font? Expecting something like:

```
echo "The slow cyan snail creeps under the eager cat" | render_text --font ./qqq.ttf --scale=18 -o text.png
```

I expect this to be somewhere in ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick suite.

Example use case: render the same text with multitude of fonts (and don't want to install all fonts into the system).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) command. If the font name has more than 1 word, separate them with a "-". Here are some examples using the [Kid Kosmic](http://www.dafont.com/kid-kosmic.font) font. Replace "YOURTEXT" with any phrase.

---

```
convert -pointsize 15 -font Kid-Kosmic label:"YOURTEXT" output.png
```

[image]

---

The `caption:` option enables text wrapping; but you need to specify the image size.

```
convert -pointsize 15 -font Kid-Kosmic -size 140x100 caption:"YOURTEXT" output.png
```

[image]

---

Another one with centered text:

```
convert -pointsize 15 -font Kid-Kosmic -size 140x100 -gravity center caption:"YOURTEXT" output.png
```

[image]

Comment: [PANGRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams#Perfect_pangrams_in_English_.2826_letters.29) FAIL!

Comment: `convert: unable to read font 'Kid-Kosmic' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/807`... How to point it to the font _file_ (without permanently installing it)?

Comment: Replacing "Kid-Kosmic" with the absolute path to a True Type font works for me on Ubuntu 11.04. What OS are you using?

Comment: @flashnode It works for me too, I'm on Win7 Ultimate. Though I had to make sure the path is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: For Mac OS, use the full font path as well..
Fonts location: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201722